# Spring Integration - @InboundChannelAdapter polling

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration. We are creating our application using Spring Integration Annotations.
I have configured an @InboundChannelAdapter with poller fixed delay of 5 seconds. But the problem is as soon as I start my application on weblogic, the adapter starts polling and hits endpoint with practically no message.
We need to call a rest service and then trigger this adapter.
Is there a way to implement the same?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `autoStartup` property to `false` and use a control bus to start/stop it.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class So59469573Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So59469573Application.class, args);
    }

}

@Component
class Integration {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "channel", autoStartup = "false",
            poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
    public String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channel")
    public void handle(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "controlChannel")
    @Bean
    public ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean controlBus() {
        return new ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean();
    }

}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "controlChannel")
interface Control {

    void send(String control);
}

@RestController
class Rest {

    @Autowired
    Control control;

    @PostMapping("/foo/{command}")
    public void trigger(@PathVariable String command) {
        if ("start".equals(command)) {
            control.send("@'integration.foo.inboundChannelAdapter'.start()");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary! This solution worked perfectly. Just one small thing - IN the process, I tried to implement Poller with @ServiceActivator, it seemed to work but the message was polled for exactly 3 times and then polling stopped. What could be the reason for the same?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; it is not clear what you mean, ask a new question showing the code the question.

Comment: sure Thanks! Will put a new question.